# Covert list of lists to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Although I am quite experienced in `pandas` I always find that I miss some basic things.

Specifically, I do the following:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1, 2, 1], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]

data = np.array(data)

names = ['A', 'B', 'C']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=names)

print(df)
```

and then I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 5), indices imply (3, 3)
```

My question, can this code work like that with a non-nxn (different number of rows and columns) array?

(I am asking the question in this way since I know that it works for nxn arrays)

or the principal way is to create a dict such as:

```
{'A': [1, 2, 3, 3, 4], 'B': [1, 1, 1, 2, 1],'C': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
```

?

I get a similar error and without the `np.array()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need adding T

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data.T, columns=names)
df
Out[509]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  1  5
1  2  1  6
2  3  1  7
3  3  2  8
4  4  1  9
```

Comment: Ok cool thanks :) - Sometimes I am missing some basic things :0

Answer (score 1):

So let's go through the code a couple lines at a time for lucidity:
You're creating a list of lists:

```
    data = [[1, 2, 3, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1, 2, 1], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
    data = np.array(data)
```

The shape of this Array is (3,5) which means that the array is stored as 3 rows and 5 columns. 
So in your next line:

```
    names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=names)
```

The dataframe is created for 3 columns(which is the length of the names list) but is presented with 5 columns of data instead, thus triggering the Value Error.
Always check the shape of a multidimensional array when trying to create a pandas dataframe using the np.shape() function:

```
    np.shape(data)
```

The first number of the function output gives you the number of rows of data and the second number give you the number of columns in a 2D array.

Which is where the previous answer comes into play:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data.T, columns=names)
```

what data.T does is that it transposes the columns and rows of the array. Thereby flipping the shape of the array from (3,5) to (5,3) in order to broadcast it to the dataframe. Thus, the number of columns in the dataframe matches the number of columns in the flipped dataframe and all is well.

Another method you could use, that would also answer your question about creating a dictionary as well would be to use a dictionary comprehension and then to convert the dictionary into a dataframe:

```
    new_dict={i:data[j] for j,i in enumerate(names)}
```

The enumerate keyword is used when iterating through a list or array when we need to use both indices and elements. So here i holds the elements of 'names' while j holds the index of i in 'names'.
Here we create a dictionary in a single line with each name A,B,C individually corresponding as:

{'A':[1, 2, 3, 3, 4],'B':[1, 1, 1, 2, 1],'C':[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}

We can now finally convert this dictionary to a dataframe using:
        df=pd.DataFrame(new_dict)
Giving you the output dataframe as required.
Hope this helped!